# Grab html content from another window?

Tags: flash

Is there a way (using flash) to grab the raw html from another browser frame? I'd like the following sequence:

1. Launch my window from www.mysite.com/test
2. Launch window from another site www.yousite.com, which has content I want to grab.
3. Let my window grab the raw html content from the other window.

I doubt this is possible because it could be used for dastardly purpii, but just wanted to check.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solely via flash, no.  However you could use ExternalInterface and some javascript to do it, though you will run into some restrictions depending on the browser.  If the other window is from the same domain then you're probably fine, but if it's something completely different then XSS protection will probably kick in and block it.